# Program to get and display Bluetooth metadata

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, raspbian-jessie, software-compatibility

So I set up my Raspberry Pi 3 as a Bluetooth receiver and it is able to get sound from my phone. Is there any program (preferably graphical) that can display the track info  and artist info from AVRCP 1.3 and be able to send pause and play signals to the device?

Comment: I know this isn't a complete answer, but I am also researching this and really struggling with finding much info at all. So maybe it can be helpful as a starting point. The following post on the Raspberry Pi forums contains some Python code that did this on Wheezy (take track info and display it on an LCD screen).
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=635509#p635509 As far as I can tell it also manages the bluetooth connection itself, which is probably not what you want, as you already have this. So you would have to extract the relevant code / remove the unnecessary one and build